# ArcMap crashes with Create Enterprise Database tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to create an enterprise database. I have ArcGIS for Server enterprise edition/workgroup and ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1. Also I installed SQLEXPRESS 2012 SP1 included from Esri in the ArcMap 10.4.1 installation media and I am connected to the instance in ArcCatalog using local user authentication. Everything is on the same machine

I am trying to use the Create Enterprise Database tool and I have followed all the steps in the documentation but before the tool is completed the dialog box says Geodatabase Created Successfully and ArcMap crashes.

When I look in the DATA folder the database has been created but it is not functional.

[image: Try to connect to created db]

ArcMap also crashes if I try to connect to the db that is created with the Create Enterprise Database tool.

[image]

And then arcMap crashes

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to specify which **version** and **service pack** of SQL Server  Express  you have installed.  While Express can host enterprise geodatabases (when supported), it's  not a recommended configuration  (due to thread, RAM, and storage limitations).

Comment: So why is Express distributed by ESRI and do you have another recommendation?

Comment: Express is part of the Workgroup server family. It is not intended for use with an Enterprise license. If you want a free Enterprise class database, use PostgreSQL.

Comment: I will read up on PostgreSQL and get back with you, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From comments:

> Express is part of the Workgroup server family. It is not intended for
>   use with an Enterprise license. If you want a free Enterprise class
>   database, use PostgreSQL. – Vince May 8 at 12:17